# Confusing regex. I can't understand this part: +$/

Tags: javascript, regex

I was doing a hackerrank [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-regexp-2/problem) and I did the following code:

```
/^(Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.|Dr\.|Er\.)\w/
```

But the answer was

```
/^(Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.|Dr\.|Er\.)\w+$/
```

and I don't understand the last part of that regex. What is it?

Comment: `\w+$` just means that the pattern ends with any number of characters, while `\w` at the end just means that the thing checked by the pattern is to match a single character, but anything else is allowed after that (in theory).

Comment: Try this site for help with regex: https://regexr.com/ It allows you to enter a regex. Then it displays what the regex means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `\w` will select An alphanumeric character (“word character”), and When you put a **plus sign (+)** after something in a regular expression, it indicates that **the element may be repeated more than once.**

Thus, /\w+/ matches one or more alphanumeric characters.

And $ here means End of string.

Example 1 --- `/^(Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.|Dr\.|Er\.)\w$/.test('Mr.J'); // true`

Example 2 --- `/^(Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.|Dr\.|Er\.)\w$/.test('Mr.Joseph'); // false`

Example 3 --- `/^(Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.|Dr\.|Er\.)\w+$/.test('Mr.Joseph'); // true`

Comment: What about the `$`?  Isn't that also significant here?

Comment: Hi Pawan, your statement is right but i think it misses an imporant thing, using the plus sign forces the element to appear at least once.

Comment: sorry, I missed it, I have Edited my answer. Thanks, @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @AarónBC. I think thats what I meant when I said --- Thus, /\w+/ matches one or more alphanumeric characters. Excuse my English but by saying one or more I meant at least once.